# How to use ion-img in ionic 3 app?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an ionic 3 app which contains lot of images in different pages.I tried this,using the default HTML image tag.But using that resulted in getting lag in using the app,also getting lot of issues like images size changes when screen rotates resulting sometimes in overlapping of images,ugly loading of images.

I looked up in Ionic documentation to find out that it's better to use ion img tag to remove these issues.With that lazy loading,smooth scroll all can be achieved.I'm already using virtual scroll,but not using ion-img for images,but using img tag for loading images.

When i used ion-img as given in ionic documentation,no images are loaded only empty spaces are displayed.Here is the code,

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <button ion-button clear class="menubutton">
      <ion-icon name="menu" (click)="presentActionSheetCategory()"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title><button ion-button clear (click)="goAbout()">appname</button></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="card-background-page">
  <ion-list [virtualScroll]="categories">
          <ion-item *virtualItem="let category" class="itemcss">
              <ion-card collection-repeat="category in categories" (click)="category.golink()" class="wallcard">
                  <ion-img class='homecardimage' collection-repeat="category in categories" [src]="category.Url"></ion-img>
                  <div collection-repeat="category in categories" class="card-title">{{category.Name}}</div>
                </ion-card>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
```

How to properly implement ion-img tag in Ionic 3?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

It seems this behavior is a bug in the `virtual scroller` with `ion-img`.It has been fixed on [**this PR**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/13223).But still, it is not merged. Hope you can use [**ionic-image-loader**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader) here. You can see more [**about this issue here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13331).

**Old Feedback**

You have done it wrongly. You can try as shown below.

```
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="categories">
      <ion-item *virtualItem="let category" class="itemcss">
          <ion-card (click)="category.golink()" class="wallcard">
              <ion-img class='homecardimage' [src]="category.Url"></ion-img>
              <div class="card-title">{{category.Name}}</div>
            </ion-card>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: I actually already gave image dimensions for class 'homecardimage' in category.scss.  .homecardimage{  height:60vw;  width:100vw; }

Comment: Did you check it at runtime?  Is that applied correctly?

Comment: No images are shown only blank spaces are shown in place in ionic serve in chrome.

Comment: I meant sizes of images? Is that correct on blank images?

Comment: OK.Image dimensions are applied properly.Images are not shown,only properly dimensioned blank spaces are displayed.

Comment: Please see the Update.

Comment: Still no images are displayed.Images are displayed only when scrolled towards the end of image list.But images disappears when scrolled up,or any other case.Similar to what was happening before i asked this question.No change even after the update you recomended in ionic serve --lab.

Comment: Can you test for a few images? Maybe due to the large image list.

Comment: Still the same issue.Shows all images also not that perfectly when scrolled towards the end.Disappears,in every other case.

Comment: Also will this work in large image list?Or this issue just in ionic serve --lab chrome?

Comment: Can you test this on the device?  `ionic cordova run android --prod --device`

Comment: I tested on a real device..same issue still exists..images shown only when scrolled toward the end of image list disappears in other cases.

Comment: It seems you need to log this issue on Ionic repo with minimal working git repo of your app:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/new

Comment: After that you can try this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/

Comment: Is there any workaround/alternative for ion-img in ionic 3?

Comment: No.You must use `ion-img` due to many reasons. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/

Comment: Please see the **Update**

Comment: Can you tell me where the actual solution(if any) is?

Comment: I didn't get you.Did you see the **Update** above?

Comment: @Sampath when using ionic-image-loader does the image overlap to other card see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53281894/9253041) edit: I didnt post the when using ionic-image-loader but if I use it does it overlap images the same as my posts? Because when I use image loader it still overlap to other card

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-img class='homecardimage' collection-repeat="category in categories" src="category.Url"></ion-img>
```